# Swift - Change the minus icon on edit mode in table view

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the default left minus icon for a cell in edit mode.

I tried everything.

I am already able to change the Delete confirmation button on the right, I need only to change the left icon.

I tried to create a custom interface cell and added a custom image on the left side, then I have added this code in my view controller.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }
```

Adding that code gives me a way to hide the minus default icon and showing my own image.

The problem is that the space for the default icon remains anyway :(

I do not know what else to do. I tried using constraints in my custom cell interface, but it does not fix the issue at all.

Also when using that piece of code anyway, not only the icon goes away (that's fine apart from the white space that it leaves) but also does not show anymore the right actions when swiping. Only the drag and drop feature reamains active.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

add this function so the rows wont indent while editing